# How search specify file but you don't know in with path folder is (in bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I can find the content in all files called values.yaml with

`find . -name values.yaml | xargs grep -Re port -e target --color`

But I would like only find the values.yaml in folders called "stage", so path/bla/bla/stage/values.yaml

I have my best approach with that

`find ./*/*/*/stage/ -name values.yaml | xargs grep -Re port -e target --color`

The problem is the stage folder sometimes are in level 4, someone in level 3 or 5, etc... I would like do something like that, but doesn't work

`find ./**/stage/ -name values.yaml | xargs grep -Re port -e target --color`

There are any way to do it regardless of the level where the stage folder is located?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but assuming that you are writing a script, how about writing this in Zsh instead of bash and simply access the files by `**/stage/values.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use `-regex`:

```
find . -regex '.*/stage/.*values.yaml'
```

Or, more accurately:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/stage/?.*/values\.yaml'
```

Comment: or even `values\.yaml`

Comment: @choroba, good catch.  This also incorrectly matches paths like `./stage/foovalues.yaml`

Comment: using `-path` is much more appropriate.  Not sure if I should delete this answer: it seems to be useful, but should not be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell find to match the path:

```
find -path '*/stage/*' -name values.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on this way?

`find . -name stage -type d -exec find {} -name values.yaml \; | xargs grep -Re port -e target --color`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `caveat scriptor`: one test worked great, a different one never came back. I suspect the bad one is specific to something on my laptop, but do your own testing and don't waste time on something that's too slow.

That said:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -Re port -e target --color ./**/stage/**/values.yaml
```

Comment: Apparently something put a recursive symlink somewhere. This should be pretty safe otherwise.